# How to check if mouse is over a Image in C#

Tags: c#

[image: Application Interface]

This is the interface to a small program i am writing in C#.
I want that whenever the mouse is clicked over the image i should be able to get the x and y values of the cursor.

MessageBox.show does not show me the value for mouse pointer

```
namespace ChromaKeyerControl
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.MyMouseDown);

    }


    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }


    private void MyMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        bool entered = pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Contains(pictureBox1.PointToScreen(Cursor.Position));

      //  if( pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Contains(pictureBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)))

        if (entered)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(Cursor.Position.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You could use the `MouseEnter` (and `MouseLeave`) Event(s)

Comment: Use the events of the picturebox / imagecontrol, they will only be fired, if the mouse is over the picturebox and also will supply you with the mousecoordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to bind the mouse click with `PictureBox` not with `Form` it self

```
this.pictureBox1.MouseClick += pictureBox1_MouseClick;
```

bind the `MouseClick`, inside the event method you can get the X and Y, and then call the method you want...

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox1.MouseClick += pictureBox1_MouseClick;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.X + " - " + e.Y);
        CallAnotherMethod(e.X, e.Y);
    }
```